# Strange results with an empty href and the :link pseudo class

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, css-selectors, anchor

Here is some really simple markup and CSS:

```css
a {
  color: red;
}
a:link {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">one</a>
<a href="">two</a>
<a href>three</a>
<a>four</a>
```

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5049416f/4/)

Now from the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes):

> in HTML4, the link pseudo-classes apply to A elements with an "href"
>   attribute.

So i'd expect the first 3 links to be green.

But no, the result is actually that only the first link that has a non-empty `href` is green.

So I used inspect element and I saw that the `a:link` selector actually overides the `a` selector in all of the first 3 cases, but for some reason only applies the style on the first case.

What is going on here?

One more thing, when I tested the various browsers I noticed that Chrome,Firefox and IE11 all produced the same results, except that in Firefox, when I reload the (same) code (in the fiddle just click 'Run') - all the first 3 elements suddenly turn green.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Akshay - it looks like it will appear green as long as the href isn't empty. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5049416f/5/) I set `href="c"` and it appears green.

Comment: But when i set it to https://www.google.co.in/  it didn't work

Comment: Also applying `:hover` or `:active` works as per spec - it is something specific about `:link`

Comment: From the specs *"The `:link` pseudo-class applies for links that have not yet been visited."*. The only reason I can imagine, is that the browser sees `#` as a link that you already visited...?

Comment: Maybe because `:link` applies to sites that have not been visited yet i tried it with a link that i've never used and it worked

Comment: An empty href points to the current document. Unless you view the document in a private browsing session, an empty href should result in a visited link. It's not clear to me why any browser would treat it otherwise.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks I didn't know that an empty `href` points to the current document. However that being the case: 1) Why does inspect element show me that the `a:link` selector overides the `a` selector and 2) How do you explain what happens in FF when you click 'Run' in the fiddle?

Comment: Also keep in mind that the specific sentence you quote refers to "the link pseudo-classes" - this consists of both `:link` and `:visited`. It does not refer to only the `:link` pseudo-class.

Comment: @Danield: I can't explain any of this behavior, sorry.

Comment: @Danield This is pure speculation on my part regarding your first question but this may be because `a:link` is more specific than `a`. `a:visited` is also handled in strange ways depending on the browser http://jsfiddle.net/hco8bb5v/. It would almost seem that the dev tools only take into account specificity and not relevance in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

This would appear to be due to the way individual browsers chose to handle unvisited links. The W3 spec (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes) states:

> The :link pseudo-class applies for links that have not yet been visited.

Chrome (and Opera) see `href=""` and `href` as being the current url and thus deem them as visited. Firefox and IE treat `href=""` and `href` as unvisited until you actually click on them.

**IE (unclicked):**

[image]

**Chrome (unclicked):**

[image]

To support this logic, adding a fifth link with `href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371788/strange-results-with-an-empty-href-and-the-link-pseudo-class"` (this page) will result in a `red` link in Chrome (similar to the `href=""` and `href` links) because it sees the page as visited.

```css
a {
  color: red;
}
a:link {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">one</a>
<a href="">two</a>
<a href>three</a>
<a>four</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371788/strange-results-with-an-empty-href-and-the-link-pseudo-class">five</a>
<a href="unvisited">six</a>
```